# Problem while changing CSS using php

Tags: php, css

I am trying to change my css file using php, so in order to do so, I changed my default.css into default.php and put a `<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>` in the top, then using a form I take input from the user and change the css using php. I could successfully done it, but problem is it's showing the following error, which I cant figure it out why?

fyi: in the index page `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.php">` I put this to make sure, that index page still get its stylesheet.php

> Warning: Cannot modify header
>   information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\asterisk\default.php:2)
>   in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\asterisk\default.php
>   on line 2

Comment: Are you using Gzip compression?

Answer (score 0):

If you're setting headers make sure that you call the `header()` function at the top of the page, or at least do some `ob_flush()` before headers are sent if text must be on the page.

Comment: Also can use `ob_start()` as you suggested.

Comment: `ob_flush()` or `ob_end_clean()` should be used on bottom ..not at the top

Comment: read on ob_flush manual "you have to call ob_get_contents() before ob_flush() as the buffer contents are discarded after ob_flush() is called. " and also in example "begin with ob_start();
Then you need
ob_flush();
flush();
before any echo or print."

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all: You use [`header`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) after sending content to the client. You must make sure, that `header` is called before *any* content is sent. Look for `header('Content-Type: text/css')` or something like that. It must be used before any inline CSS and before any `print` or `echo` statements.

Answer (score 0):

That error is common when you echo or print something, before calling a `header` command.

Answer (score 0):

so in default.php at line 2 it start output. 
Set up header before this ... and all b Ok .

Answer (score 0):

**Reason :** *Warning: Cannot modify header information* error comes when some output already has been sent to the browser before calling of `header()`

**Solution:** use `ob_start()` at the top of the page just after `<?php`
**Best Practice :** also use `exit()` just after `header()`

[REFERENCE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)